# Visual Studio shortcut for showing dropdown of available Enum values for function argument

Tags: visual-studio

When calling an overloaded argument in visual studio, visual studio often doesn't show the dropdown of available enumerated values available for a function argument.  Is there a shortcut one can use the force the dropdown to be displayed, so one doesn't have to type the fully qualified path to the enum declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL + SHIFT + SPACEBAR to show methods overloads

CTRL + SPACEBAR to show Enum values